# Accessing an array inside an xml item in React

Tags: reactjs, xml

I'm trying to access the children: Array(3) on the first line on this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nkujj.png)

I'm using the react-xml-parser I installed with npm.
Here's the code I wrote:

```
const [feed, setFeed] = useState([]);
let xmlParser = new XMLParser();
let apiUrl = "...";
let xmlItems = [];

useEffect( () => { 
    axios.get(apiUrl)
       .then(({data}) => {
          var parsedData = xmlParser.parseFromString(data);
          xmlItems = parsedData.getElementsByTagName('item');
          setFeed(xmlItems);
        })
}, []);

console.log(feed[0]);
```

Comment: maybe you need to console.log(feed[0].children);

Comment: That doesn't work for me